# If Query In Sidebar

Tags: php, wp-query

I'm trying to create a query that

IF there is a value in the 'FeaturedQuote' custom field, then this shows

```
<h3 class="featuredquote"><blockquote><span class="bqstart">&#8220;</span><?php
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    echo get_post_meta($postid, 'FeaturedQuote', true);
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
<span class="bqend">&#8221;</span></blockquote>
</h3>
```

IF NOT, this shows:

```
<img src="<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    echo get_post_meta($postid, 'InsertFullImg', true);
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>">
```

I cant get it right!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assign the return value of the first check to a variable, and test if there is something in it:

```
if ( $quote = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'FeaturedQuote', TRUE ) )
{
?><h3 class="featuredquote"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<blockquote><span class="bqstart">&#8220;</span><?php
    echo $quote;
    ?>
<span class="bqend">&#8221;</span></blockquote>
<?php
}
elseif ( $img = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'InsertFullImg', TRUE ) )
{
    echo "<img src='$img' alt=''>";
}
```

Note, a `<h3>` cannot be the parent of a `<blockquote>`. Headlines can contain inline elements only.

Comment: Thanks. This works but returns the img url for the image. How can I place in <img> tags?

Comment: @emailsforben See my update.